# How to I get verbose (or debug) output with SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl

I've got a working SOAP::Lite client. It works against an established server, but so far my development server is sending back nothing except a 404. (Which is odd, because I'm not even seeing a connection on the server end.)

The closest parallel that I'm used to is `Net::FTP`.

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( "some.host.name", Debug => 1 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see the documentation for [SOAP::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-Lite/lib/OldDocs/SOAP/Lite.pm#SOAP::Trace)? I haven't tried it myself, but it all sounds really promising.

Comment: That works. Weird that there's not a section like that in my doc.

Comment: It's also weird that the URL I posted points to something called 'OldDocs'. No idea what's going on there.

Answer (score 3):

Might I recommend using a tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the network traffic of your SOAP app to see exactly what's going on in the network.  You should be able to right-click on a series of packets and select "Follow TCP Stream" to see the full HTTP exchange.

Comment: It's a good idea, but we're an IT shop in a larger business. I can't just install useful apps on my own.